# Chrome extenstion : Angular component receiving messages from background script

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension

I have chrome extension in angular 8
Have a background script with a context menu on the right click
I want to send some info on context menu click, and typically done the receiving part in content scripts

I tried this kind of code in my app.component.ts

```
      ngOnInit():void {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( data => console.log("content: ",data));

  }
```

But background script gets

> _generated_background_page.html:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

So, looks like I am not properly initializing content scripts inside my angular app.

I tried something like this in my manifest.json with no luck

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["main.js","scripts.js","common.js"]
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Try [document_start](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time).

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately same thing. 
Do you have by any chance any examples of angular 2+ app which has content script functionality describe in angular components and "receives messages"?

I can query the tab and etc ,so I can contact the chrome API
But, it looks like my angular code and background scripts doest see each other

Comment: No, I don't. The problem is that ngOnInit doesn't run at all, apparently.

Comment: @VladyslavDidenko have you found out how to solve this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @AfeezAziz Not the angular way atleast. What I did is that I included 2 plain/vanilla JS files and pointed back to them in my content script section. 
So, I have mix of Angular & JS files. No a perfect fix, but I dont have too much logic in there, so for now it works.
If you find a better way, drop it here - so I can include it in response